# How to identify fake call log entries in the Android call log database?

Tags: logging, hardware

Is there a way to discriminate between real call events and fake call log entries (made using some app) from the call log database in Android?

Comment: Welcome on IT Security SE. This question is very specific to Android systems, and may therefore be more suitable on [android.se] website.

Comment: The answer is obvious. You don't.  You ask the network operator for call logs.